# twitter bootstrap popover doesn't work with angularjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, popover

I was trying to use twitter bootstrap popover on my webpage when I discover that it doesn't work when it is placed below a `<div>` with `ng-repeat`. It works fine at the top within a div class that doesn't contain `ng-` does anyone know why did it happen and how can I work around the issue?

```
<h3>Students Without Team</h3>
 <div class="accordion" id="studentNoTeamAccordion" >
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" rel="popover"data-html="true"
            data-content="
               <form>
                   <textarea class='input-xlarge' rows='12' type='text'></textarea>  
                   <P>
                      <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Send' />
               </form>"
            data-placement="right" data-original-title="Enquiries">Send Enquiries
        </a>
  <div class="accordion-group" ng-repeat="(key,val) in stud_finding"><
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" rel="popover"data-html="true"
         data-content="
               <form>
                   <textarea class='input-xlarge' rows='12' type='text'></textarea> 
                   <P>
                       <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Send' />
               </form>"
```

Comment: You'll need to post a plunker or a fiddle for anyone to be able to troubleshoot this. But in the meantime, are you aware of [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap)? It provides pure AngularJS implementations of the Twitter Bootstrap jQuery libraries.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! i will look into it, mean while i will also try to post a plunker soon. Thanks! =D

Comment: I also dont understand why this question is down voted.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see why this question got down-voted. It's a good example on how to understand the principle of scopes in angular. A scope is basically attached to a DOM element. All the controllers, repeats, etc. will only work in this DOM element (the scope). When Boostrap creates a popover, it creates a new DOM element and appends it to body, so now it's out of the scope (it is not in the element any more). That's a key feature to understand about Angular.

Luckily, Bootstrap has the solution. Popover has a `container` option that lets you append the popover to a specific element instead of body. Put there the jQuery selector of the DOM element that has the angular controller. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers (see Options)

Answer (score 6):

At the moment there are at lest 2 projects that got Bootstrap's popover directives for AngularJS written already:

- http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/
- http://mgcrea.github.com/angular-strap/

The difference is that http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ is native AngularJS directives so you don't need any 3rd party JavaScript dependencies.

Both projects are hosted on GitHub so you can see implementations and either learn from them, decide to change or just use one of the projects.

Comment: would it interfere with twitter bootstrap?

Comment: both projects demo popover with older versions of angular. when you test modern angular code like 1.0.6 or 1.1.4 it stops working. Popover and tooltip are useless unless they add partial template options.

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure what you mean by "stops working" since at least directives from http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ are working fine with the latest AngularJS: http://plnkr.co/edit/FECkoAJgSbBVFdvzk6mx?p=preview

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource your example is a tooltip, not popover.  popover is not working. (works: h and this one... (does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/tvAhW/ttp://jsfiddle.net/msgilligan/UYjkK/)

Comment: @Richard Hmmm, Popovers seem to work as well with 1.1.4: http://plnkr.co/edit/FIfvbix2JIMIOwlH5w1M?p=preview

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource your code works on plunker but does not work on jfiddle

Comment: @Richard the example in your fiddle has nothing to do with code examples I was showing in plunker. My point was that directives from http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ work without problems with the latest AngularJS, since you were claiming otherwise.