# ng-click and ng-model not working in a popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ng-click in in a bootstrap popover that doesnt seem to work. when I move it out of the popup into the page it seems to work. Also the ng-model value doesnt seem to update either.

```
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
<input type="text" placeholder="Quote ID" ng-model="selectedItems.quote.label">
<button type="button" ng-click="newQuote()">New quote</button>
</div>
```

Is this because the popover is created in the dom and angular does not know it exists? Any ideas how I can get it to work? Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the newQuote

```
 $scope.newQuote = function() {
        $scope.selectedItems.quote = angular.copy(defaultQuote);

        $scope.solution.quotes.push($scope.selectedItems.quote);

        $scope.selectedItems.quote.label = 'New Quote';

        $scope.addMessage('Quote created successfully', 2);
    };
```

EDIT 2

Here is a plunker showing the issue - the alert is not displayed when ng-click="newQuote()" is fired
http://plnkr.co/edit/ANH98vlflPK9c5qA3ohO?p=preview

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it doesn't work", is it giving you an error or not showing anything in the popover?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle or a plunker that shows your problem? That would help

Comment: Is the html bound to the correct scope? Select the button element in your favorite browser and type `angular.element($0).scope()`. Check if it has you `newQuote` method.

Comment: heres a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ANH98vlflPK9c5qA3ohO?p=preview

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create a `Directive` to make angular works with `Bootstrap Popover`. You can take a look in your Developer console when using Bootstrap Popover. It actually does not reuse the `DOM` that you predefined - ie :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Quote ID" ng-model="selectedItems.quote.label">
<button type="button" ng-click="newQuote()">New quote</button>
```

But add in a new piece of `DOM` - ie

```
<div class="popover fade bottom in" role="tooltip" id="popover770410" style="top: 30px; left: 0px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow" style="left: 15.9420289855072%;">

        </div><h3 class="popover-title">New quote</h3><div class="popover-content"> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Quote ID" ng-model="selectedItems.quote.label" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        <button type="button" ng-click="newQuote()">New quote</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore `Angular` will not understand new piece of `DOM` because it has not compiled yet - ie : You cannot use `ng-click` as well as `ng-modal`. One way to work around this is to create a `directive` and `compile` your `html` content before passing that piece of `DOM` to `Bootstrap Popover`.

I have created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/qkwdnjdy/) to demonstrate this idea.

As you can see :

1. I have compile you `content` and bind it to current `scope`

   ```
   $compile(content)(scope);
   ```
2. Before passing that piece of `DOM` to `popover`

   ```
   var options = {
       content: compileContent,
       html: true,
       title: title
   };
   $(elem).popover(options);
   ```

With this way to can let Angular understand new piece of `DOM` added and do its work correspondingly.

Furthermore, actually there quite some `directives` that works with `Bootstrap Popover` that you can take a look at instead of creating new `directives`

1. [AgularUI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
2. [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)

Reference :

1. http://tech.pro/tutorial/1360/bootstrap-popover-using-angularjs-compile-service
2. [twitter bootstrap popover doesn't work with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907376/twitter-bootstrap-popover-doesnt-work-with-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you for explaining helped a lot.

Comment: Excellent write up and explanation! Very easy to implement.