# Putting popover inside td

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6 and there is a problem with putting popover inside a `<td>`. So please can you help me how to overcome this problem?

This is my HTML code.

```
<html>
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th>Content status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="ConfigurationData in crawlConfigurationData">
      <td>
        <a class="col-sm-7" href="" data-ng-click="getContent(ConfigurationData)">{{ConfigurationData.url}}</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</html>
```

below one is my javascript code to get the popover

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle = "popover"]').popover();
});
</script>
```

Comment: it works. Tried your code on bootsnipp, and it works. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/86EyZ if you want the popover to appear on hover (currently it appears when the link is clicked - focus) change focus to hover

Comment: no actually it is working when i put outside the table but when  i write the same code inside  table <td></td> tag it is not  working.  @JapanGuy

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/NjMqp it works here inside a table. Need to see more of your code to figure the problem out

Comment: copy pasted your code and it worked. Does it work if you change `data-trigger="focus"` to  `data-trigger="hover"` ?

Comment: yaa for me everything working out side the table data-trigger="focus", "click","hover".but  inside the table nothing is working out.unable to find the issue whether the problem is with in the table or ng-repeat or what is going wrong i don't understand and in bootsnip which version of bootstrap they are using iam using 3.3.6 is there any problem with this version? @JapanGuy

Comment: you mean when you put the same code outside <table> it does work, but doesnt inside it? Have you tried to look at a debugger (usually ctrl+shift+i on browsers), the console should show you if there are any javscript errors

Comment: the bootstrap version I was testing your code at was 3.3.0

Comment: you mean when you put the same code outside <table> it does work, but doesnt inside it? yes exactly...same code working outside. and no javascript errors too..iam using firebug as a debugging tool  if there are any javascript errors it should'nt work outside the table too.but it does work outside. @JapanGuy

Comment: if you notice something out of the box please let me know..and really thanks for the quick response. @JapanGuy

Comment: no worries, after some googling found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907376/twitter-bootstrap-popover-doesnt-work-with-angularjs . Seems like you need a separate bootstrap for angular. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ this is the solution probably

Comment: Thank you,hope it really helps me.. @JapanGuy

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago but for people having trouble i figured the issue to be the ng-repeat, when you run `$(document).ready(function(){$('[data-toggle = "popover"]').popover();});` even tho the `document` is ready, the elements within ng-repeat haven't loaded yet. I used directives to solve this, using above's example it will look like this:

```
    <html>
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th>Content status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="ConfigurationData in crawlConfigurationData" load-popover>
      <td>
        <a class="col-sm-7" href="" data-ng-click="getContent(ConfigurationData)">{{ConfigurationData.url}}</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</html>
```

And my directive:

```
.directive('loadPopover', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if(scope.$last){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
    })
    }
  };
})
```

Although the right way to go with this would be to use UI-Bootstrap, seems like it doesn't support newer Bootstrap/AngularJS versions